# table with \RaggedRight using tabularray package

Tags: columns, tabularray

I can set table columns to be left and right, but my question if there is an easier way to set the columns to be ragged:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\begin{document}    

\begin{center}
% Style changes
\small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
% tabular
\small
\begin{tblr}{width=0.9\textwidth, colspec={X[l]|X[c]|X[r]}}
    \hline
    variable (left)   & 
    variable (center) &
    variable (right)  \\ \hline
    %
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

%Using RaggedRight and RaggedLeft
\begin{tblr}{width=0.9\textwidth, colspec={>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X|>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X|>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}}
    \hline
    variable (left)   & 
    variable (center) &
    variable (right)  \\ \hline
    %
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to load `tabularx`. I think loading `tabularray` package is enough for typesetting tables.

Comment: @User23456234: That is right, I needed it for the example for `\arraybackslash`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could redefine the `\TblrAlign...` macros:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ragged2e}




\begin{document}    

\begin{center}
\small
\RenewDocumentCommand\TblrAlignLeft{}{\RaggedRight}
\RenewDocumentCommand\TblrAlignCenter{}{\Centering}
\RenewDocumentCommand\TblrAlignRight{}{\RaggedLeft}
\begin{tblr}{width=0.9\textwidth, colspec={X[l]|X[c]|X[r]}}
    \hline
    variable (left)   & 
    variable (center) &
    variable (right)  \\ \hline
    %
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tblr}{width=0.9\textwidth, colspec={X[l]|X[c]|X[r]}}
    \hline
    variable (left)   & 
    variable (center) &
    variable (right)  \\ \hline
    %
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column & 
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but that is for the whole document and specific for a table. I would prefer if that could be set specific for a tabular.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech You could make the redefinition inside a group around the table.